# Multiple start options for Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging

Sure, unit tests are fine, but sometimes you want to do a system test or debug a certain situation. In that case, you might use the start options of Visual Studio, which can be found in the project properties, Debug section:

[image: Visual Studio Start Options]

Now it may happen that you have a few settings which you use more often, and I wonder whether someone has implemented an add-on to Visual Studio that allows to define many of these options and just select them from a list.

It should be

- for Visual Studio 2013 and higher
- for Windows (obviously)
- cost less than 20 USD, gratis preferred, Open Source preferred

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the command line to start Visual Studio?  That would allow you to write a script that defines how to start VS based on your requirements.

Comment: @rrirower: because I have VS already open and it takes some time to start it with all plugins like NCrunch, ReSharper etc. When I make a fix and I'd like to test in say 3 different scenarios, I don't want to restart VS 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Smart Commandline Arguments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MBulli.SmartCommandlineArguments) in the Visual Studio Marketplace.

It

- allows specifying multiple command line arguments
- allows selecting and deselecting command line arguments
- works on VS 2015 and higher only, unfortunately
- works on Windows
- is gratis

If you can't see the window, it's under *View / Other Windows / Commandline Arguments*.

If you have file names with spaces, don't forget to add quotation marks.

[image: Screenshot]